# Julia error VS Code and Juno / Erro Julia VS Code e Juno

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, julia

Quando eu tento fazer um programa básico como este no VS Code:

```
n = 0
while n < 10
    n+=1
    println(n)
end
```

eu recebo esse erro:

```
    ERROR: syntax: unexpected end
```

Eu tentei fazer o mesmo programa no Juno (a versão JuliaPro) e eu recebo este outro erro, que também não faz sentido pra mim:

```
    LoadError: UndefVarError: n not defined
```

qual o erro que estou cometendo?

Comment: mas não pode estar em outra língua, junto com português?

Comment: Não há porquê. Todos os usuários deste site falam português. Inglês seria apenas se postasse sua pergunta no [so], que embora é da mesma rede, é um site diferente.

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com a [documentação do Julia](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/index.html), você deve fazer assim:

```
julia> i = 1;

julia> while i <= 5
           println(i)
           global i += 1
       end
```

O erro que apareceu é devido a variavel `n` ser declarada fora de escopo como está [descrito aqui](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Core.UndefVarError), exemplo:

```
julia> a
ERROR: UndefVarError: a not defined

julia> a = 1;

julia> a
1
```

Sobre escopo de variáveis você tambem pode encontrar na [documentação](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/#scope-of-variables-1)

Comment: E quanto ao "unexpected end"?

Comment: nao compreendo muito da linguagem, mas é base de programação que normalmente o seu "end" foi utilizado mas o interpretador ou compilador não reconhece aquela instrução naquele determinado ponto do código, possivelmente causado por erro de sintaxe